# Busca em tabela relacionada

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um script de busca que varre até três campos de uma tabela chamada produtos, agora preciso fazer uma pesquisa em uma tabela chamada marca, a tabela produto tem o id_marca que se relaciona com a tabela marca, mas não estou conseguindo implementar.

A pesquisa está assim:

```
$pesquisa = $_REQUEST['s'];
$pesquisa = (strtolower($pesquisa));    

// Agrupando campos no concat.
$campo = 'CONCAT(descricao, " ", resumo, " ", detalhes, " ", codigo_msb)';
// dividindo as palavras pelo espaço
$palavras = explode( " ", $pesquisa );  
// eliminando ítens vazios 
$palavras = array_filter($palavras);

// Inicializando a variável
$where = '';
$cola = 'WHERE ';

foreach ($palavras as $palavra) {
  // Removendo espaços em branco
  $palavra = trim($palavra);      
  $palavra = mysql_real_escape_string($palavra, $conexao); 
  $where .= $cola.$campo.' LIKE "%'.$palavra.'%" ';
  $cola = 'AND ';
}

mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsBusca = "SELECT 
                      produtos.id_marca,                          
                      marca.descricao AS marca  
                    FROM
                      produtos
                      INNER JOIN marca ON (produtos.id_marca = marca.id_marca) ".$where." ";
$rsBusca = mysql_query($query_rsBusca, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsBusca = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsBusca);
$totalRows_rsBusca = mysql_num_rows($rsBusca);
```

A tabela produtos tem o id_marca que se relaciona com a tabela marca e preciso fazer uma busca pelo nome da marca.

O erro que está ocorrendo é esse:

```
Column 'descricao' in where clause is ambiguous
```

Comment: A dúvida é sobre alguma lógica do PHP ou sobre o comando SQL? Se é sobre SQL, você pode deixar a pergunta mais clara mostrando apenas o código SQL. Além disso, escreva o que você já tentou até agora e os problemas encontrados.

Comment: Olá @Caffe, sim, minha dúvida é sobre SQL, estou fazendo um um Join mas o mesmo está falhando.

Comment: Onde está o JOIN então? Não aparece no código que você postou. E o que quer dizer com "está falhando"? Dá algum erro?

Comment: Acabei de atualizar a pergunta com o Join, mas como uso o concat para fazer a busca nos campos da tabela produtos sem referência a tabela marca o erro ocorre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está lá no começo do seu código (a explicação é o que o Fernando disse, tem mais de uma coluna com o mesmo nome envolvida na query):

```
$campo = 'CONCAT(descricao, " ", resumo, " ", detalhes, " ", codigo_msb)';
```

A solução depende de qual descrição você quer usar no `WHERE`. Supondo que seja a do produto:

```
$campo = 'CONCAT(produtos.descricao, " ", resumo, " ", detalhes, " ", codigo_msb)';
```

---

Sobre seu último comentário, isto:

```
WHERE produtos CONCAT(...
```

deveria ser:

```
WHERE CONCAT(...
```

Comment: Olá @bfavaretto, não consigo entender, sempre que altero a referência, ou seja o alias continuo com o erro, veja a mensagem:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT(produtos.descricao, " ", resumo, " ", detalhes, " ", codigo_msb) LIKE "%s' at line 6

Comment: O echo está assim: SELECT p.id_marca, m.descricao AS marca FROM produtos as p INNER JOIN marca as m ON (p.id_marca = m.id_marca) WHERE produtos CONCAT(produtos.descricao, " ", resumo, " ", detalhes, " ", codigo_msb) LIKE "%sofa%"

Comment: @adventistapr Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

O erro que você postou já está dizendo explicitamente qual é o erro. É o seguinte a tabela `produtos` também deve conter uma coluna chamada `descricao`, certo? Então como você não está utilizando **alias** em sua consulta, está ocorrendo esse erro: `Column 'descricao' in where clause is ambiguous`, como você postou na pergunta. Pois o banco de dados não sabe de qual tabela você quer utiliza a coluna `descricao`, já que ela está nas duas tabelas.

Então o que você deve fazer é o seguinte:

- Colocar `alias` na consulta em suas tabelas;
- Utilizar os `alias` para indicar de qual tabela você deseja a coluna explicitamente;

Segue o código modificado:

```
// modifique seu `where` que é o que está causando o problema
// coloquei como alias "p ou m", pois não sei de qual tabela você quer
$where .= $cola.'p ou m'.$campo.' LIKE "%'.$palavra.'%" ';

// adicione o alias a sua consulta
$query_rsBusca = "SELECT 
                      p.id_marca,                          
                      m.descricao AS marca  
                    FROM
                      produtos as p
                      INNER JOIN marca as m ON (p.id_marca = m.id_marca) ".$where." ";
```

Ou como percebi que ao invés de `alias` você estava utilizando o nome da tabela que funciona similar ao `alias`. Você simplesmente pode no `where` adicionar o nome da tabela para especificar de qual é a coluna do `where`:

```
// coloquei como alias "produto ou marca", pois não sei de qual tabela você quer
$where .= $cola.'produto ou marca'.$campo.' LIKE "%'.$palavra.'%" ';
```

> Eu para evitar esse tipo de problema, já me acostumei por *default* a sempre utilizar alias, em minhas consultas para todos os campos mesmo que não sejam ambíguos.

Sua [segunda duvida(nos comentários)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47087/busca-em-tabela-relacionada/47107?noredirect=1#comment94840_47107), é como @bfavaretto, citou:

```
WHERE produtos CONCAT(...
```

deveria ser:

```
WHERE CONCAT(...
```

> <sup>Código ([segunda duvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47087/busca-em-tabela-relacionada/47107?noredirect=1#comment94840_47107)) retirado da resposta do @bfavaretto</sup>
>
> Criei um exemplo iterativo da solução completa, [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0a684/1).

Comment: Olá @Fernando, muito obrigado por ter respondido, fiz as alterações conforme seu modelo, agora estou recebendo uma mensagem, veja:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT(descricao, " ", resumo, " ", detalhes) LIKE "%anc%"' at line 6

Comment: @adventistapr, agora parece ser um erro de SQL, de um echo em `$query_rsBusca` antes de executar a `query`, e poste o SQL completo que está sendo executado, para pode tentar lhe ajudar.

Comment: Olha o echo:SELECT p.id_marca, m.descricao AS marca FROM produtos as p INNER JOIN marca as m ON (p.id_marca = m.id_marca) WHERE produtos CONCAT(descricao, " ", resumo, " ", detalhes) LIKE "%anc%" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT(descricao, " ", resumo, " ", detalhes) LIKE "%anc%"' at line 6

Comment: Essa sua segundo duvida é conforme o @bfavaretto, citou, você deve remover o "produtos " antes do CONCAT. Fiz um [exemplo online de seu problema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0a684/1) para ajudar a entender sua estrutura, de uma olhada no seu SQL corrigido.

Comment: @adventistapr, editei a resposta, complementando com as informações referentes a essa sua segunda duvida.